# Do I need to fix the weight of likeret scale values on surveymonky before exporting to SPSS

Tags: statistics, spss, surveymonkey

I've done a survey on survey monkey and collected the number of responses I need. However, now that I am about to analyze the data, I noticed that I started the likert scale with "Agree" instead of "Strongly disagree". 
So my likert scale is the following:

> agree(weight=1) strongly agree(weight =2) neutral(weight =3)
>   disagree(weight =4) strongly disagree(weight =5).

I was planning on exporting the data directly from surveymonkey to SPSS, 
my question is, does this mistake affect the analysis? do I need to change the weight of "agree" to 2? and strongly agree to 1? 
and if so, can I do that in surveymonkey or that will miss up my data?

Answer (score 2):

You can transform your data to be in any other likert scale than the respondent answered in without messing up your data. This could be done in SPSS Syntax, or through the menu. I also suggest to transform 'Strongly Agree' as 5 and 'Strongly Disagree' as 1 because 5 > 1 and most of the times 'Strongly Agree' is better than 'Strongly Disagree'.

```
RECODE q_1 (1=4) (2=5) (3=3) (4=2) (5=1).
VALUE LABELS q_1
1 'Strongly Disagree'
2 'Disagree'
3 'Neither agree nor disagree'
4 'Agree'
5 'Strongly Agree'.
EXECUTE.
```

Although, keep in mind that the misstake could have been confusing for the respondent because the answer choices was not in a logical order, so people could have answered 'Strongly Agree' but intended to answer 'Agree'.

Comment: Good answer, +1! However, you may want to [RECODE](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-recode-command/) INTO new variables. Or even better, [CLONE VARIABLES](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/clone-variables/) and then RECODE. Like so you can compare old/new values and labels using [CROSSTABS](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-crosstabs-command/). Finally, note that manually entered value labels are not appended to [SPSS' journal file](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/five-reasons-for-not-relying-on-the-journal-file/). Better use syntax for doing so.